# Does jQuery load show no content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a index.html file with a div container:

```
<div class="Widget"></div>
```

In the index.html there is also a jquery code, which should load the content of another html file and put this as content in the widget:

```
            $( ".Widget" ).load( "loadTest.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
            if ( status == "error" ) {
                alert("error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            } else {    
                alert(￼"Success"); 
            } 
        });
```

I get the alert "Success" but no content in my "Widget" div.
The loadTest.html looks like this:

```
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
    My content 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you get a log like in developer console of the browser `jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Exper/Desktop/loadTest.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, https.`

Comment: Hi,
Please check the value of status. You are checking the value of status only with the error string. But, there may be a possibility that you may get another status like "success", "notmodified", "timeout", or "parsererror".

Comment: console status object or check for other statuses as said above, this is a bad practice to just check for error and assume it is success , you should atleast check for success and error always

Comment: the alert(status) returns also "success". There is no log in the developer console

Comment: Look in your Network tab in the Developer Tools and see what the response from the server actually was - what the status was, and what the response contained.